# Lambda function timing out while attempting to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, npm, aws-lambda

I have been trying to create an AWS Lambda function that pulls information using a node module and returns it. I have been trying the following code:

```
const { getChart } = require('billboard-top-100');

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {

            getChart('artist-100', '', (err, chart) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                resolve(chart);
            });

        }, 0);
    });
}
```

which has been timing out when tested with AWS. I am not quite sure what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried returning the promise in many different formats, but none work. The server should return the data if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: how long is it running before timing out?

Comment: @AdilHindistan it is running as long as I set it to allow

Comment: Presumably, that library would call out to a website, so the timeout is likely caused by a network connectivity problem. Is that AWS Lambda function attached to a VPC? If so, is there a reason for this? Try disconnecting it from the VPC and see whether that helps.

Comment: You should reject the promise if error occurs. Also check the cloudwatch logs it should  show the relative info. 
Or try debugging the function by adding logs.